# On proving that a infinite intersection of truth sets is empty and on the usefulness of almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I am trying to solve the exercise at the end of this page, the framework is that of measure theory where we are tossing a coin infinitely often so we are working with a probability triple $( \Omega, F, P)$, where $w$ is a point of $\Omega$, $\Omega =[H,T]^N, \qquad w =(w_1, w_2, \dots ), \quad w_n \in \{H,T \},$ and

$$F = \sigma(\{ w \in \Omega : w_n = W  \}: n \in N, W \in \{H,T\})$$

The formal definition (2.3,b) that is cited in the text below is

$$F^* =  \left \{ w : \frac{\text{number of } (k \le n : w_k = H)}{n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \right \}  $$

[image]

I think that for any $w$ an $\alpha$ s.t. $w \notin F_\alpha$ is $\alpha(k) = 1$, correct?

Moreover I am missing the importance of this discussion, why is the fact that the intersection is the empty set important?

Comment: No, you need $\alpha(1)<\alpha(2)<\dots$. As to why it matters, I bet the discussion in the book continues after the exercise.

Comment: Could you please let us know the source of your excerpt?

Comment: @zoli This is from Probability with Martingales by Williams.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you for your answer but why $\alpha(1) < \alpha(2) < \dots$ ?  The discussion continues saying that the concept of almost surely give us (i) absolute precision and (ii) flexibility to avoid self-contradictions. But I am still missing the importance of the exercise.

Comment: Why $\alpha(1)<\alpha(2)<\dots$? Two reasons: (i) It says so right there in the statement of the problem! (ii) The idea is that $(\omega_{\alpha(k)})$ is supposed to be a _subsequence_ of $(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)$. That's part of the definition of "subsequence".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry I thought that was already the final result. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding why it matters, I posted an "answer" just now. Read it quick before it gets nuked for imprecision...

Comment: "It matters" because it shows, on an explicit (and, supposedly, easy to grasp) example, that the statement that, for every alpha, the property F_alpha holds almost surely cannot be replaced by the statement that the property F_alpha holds for every alpha, almost surely. In turn, as Williams explains, this example shows the need for rigor in the treatment of "events that they never happen", which the framework of measure theory provides.

Comment: *Typo: "events that never happen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a little fuzzy. It's a fuzzy question on a fuzzy topic... the whole point is why axiomatic measure-theoretic probability theory was needed to unfuzzify things.

A person might attempt to *define* probability in terms of those limits: By "definition", saying that $P(H)=1/2$ means that that limit is $1/2$.

Then when someone else points out that the sequence $HHH\dots$ is *possible* the reply is that that's not a "random" sequence. Hard to argue with that since we haven't defined random...

So. We've attempted to define $P=1/2$ by saying that it *means* that we get asymptotically half heads in any "random" sequence of tosses. But now wait, we have a problem. If we make a "random"  sequence of tosses then the results from the odd-numbered tosses should certainly still count as "random", so half the odd-numbered tosses must also be heads. And the same for *any* subsequence of tosses.

The exercise shows this can't work, by showing that it simply can't happen that half of *any* subsequence of tosses is heads. No matter what sequence we toss, there's some subsequence that violates this. So our definition leads to a contradiction. Bad.

Comment: Wow thanks this was very helpful, now I still need to find the $\alpha$ that proves that the intersection of the exercise is empty, could I have some help? And why is "almost surely" a better way of doing things?

Comment: Given $\omega$ you need to find a _subsequence_ which does not have half heads. Hmm. A subsequence consisting of nothing but heads would do. Or a subsequence with no heads. "Almost surely" is better because we know the definition

Comment: Could I choose $\alpha(k) = m$ s.t. $ w_m = H$? is this allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What you _wrote_ looks like $\alpha(1)=\alpha(2)$ again. What I suspect you meant is this: Let $\alpha(1)$ be the smallest $m$ with $\omega_m=H$. Let $\alpha_2$ be the second-smallest $m$ with $\omega_m=H$, etc. That works fine, _if_ infinitely many of the $\omega_j=H$. If only finitely many $\omega_j=H$ then...

Comment: Choose $\alpha_n$ to be nth-smallest $m$ with $w_m = T$? Choosing functions in this way is possible from the axiom of choice?

Comment: @Monolite The axiom of choice to guarantee the existence of a minimum of every nonempty subset of N... Sure about that?

Comment: No sorry I reread the answer last night and realised we were fine. Thank you too @Did :).